# Creating a button programmatically in Windows Phone 7 (WP7)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a Button in Windows phone 7 without making use of the .xaml file. I was able to create a button programmatically as follows :

```
                Button btn = new Button() { Content = "Button" }; 
                btn.Width = 148;
                btn.Height = 148;
                Thickness margin = new Thickness(x, y, x1, 400);
                btn.Margin = margin;
```

This works fine. But how do I listen to the click event of this button. If it was created using the .xaml file, the listener function would have been created automatically when double-clicked on the button in the preview window. How can I create it in this case.

Be advised, I am a newbie in WP7 programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`btn.Click +=` ... (after the += you can push tab twice to add an event handler).